# how to set in textview same sizes

Tags: android

I need to implement textview with equal sizes for 3 character, but i have got some problem if i add:
This four buttons have got diferent sizes ...but i dont know why, and how can i change

```
MOD
_X_
_(_
_5_
```

_ is white spaces..

There is xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="1dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:textSize="12sp" >
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_text_Main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:textSize="15sp" >
</TextView>
```

End there is picture of my problem:

[image: http://prntscr.com/49d6bo]

Comment: Add XML code that you have try

Comment: u can set button size fixed instead of wrap_content

Comment: try to use [gridview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="4"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="MC_"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="MS_"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="M+_"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="_(_"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="_)_"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="MC_"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="MS_"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="M+_"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="_(_"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="_)_"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="MC_"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="MS_"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="M+_"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="_(_"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="_)_"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="MC_"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="MS_"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="M+_"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="_(_"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="_)_"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="MC_"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="MS_"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="M+_"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="_(_"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="_)_"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your TextView a fix size width by changing **layout_width** from **wrap_content** to some fix dp size like **30dp**

Example:

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_text"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MOD"
        android:textSize="12sp" >
    </TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

look like you try to make button in table like in XML???

don`t know if this can help you, but when i try to make same precise width i use this...

here`s the explanation

create 1 linear layout with vertical orientation (so, everytime you add new item, it will placed to down)

inside it, insert linear layout with horizontal orientation... (insert as many row you want, in you case looks like you need 5 linear layout with horizontal orientation)

after that, insert you button / textview inside the linear layout (horizontal orientation), so your button / text will placed horizontaly.

if you want to change row, just insert the button / textview inside another linear layout (horizontal orientation).

after you insert all, set the linear layout (horizontal value) with this code

```
android:weightSum="5"
```

why 5? because in your case, u make 5 column.
and dont forget to set the width = fill parent.

after that set the button /textview inside the linearlayout (horizontal) with add this code

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

and dont forget to change the width with fill parent.

with this, i can make precise width in every row. next step you can set the margin to make your button / textview looks good.

hope this can help you...

=====================================
**here`s the code if you confuse with my explanation**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.tes.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button22"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button21"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button24"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button23"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button20"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button17"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button16"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button19"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button18"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button15"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button12"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button11"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button14"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button13"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button10"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button07"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button06"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button09"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button08"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button05"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:weightSum="5">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button04"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button03"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```